# Making a simple document/text running off page

Tags: article

the title pretty much says it all. I am a returning LaTeX user so I have forgotten some of the basics. I figured the best way to warm up would be to write a simple document but my text keeps running off the page. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Title}
\author{Me}

\begin{document} 

\maketitle 

\section{School stuff}
blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah


\end{document}
```

The strange thing is I looked at some of my old documents and none of them had this problem... Please help!!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) TeX doesn't know how to hyphenate that (rather long) word, so it doesn't. And since there are no spaces to break, the text will flow to the margins. When you write actual text it will certainly work. Ooh, I just found out that LuaTeX _does_ hyphenate that! :D

Comment: If you want to insert some text just to see the format, load the `lipsum` package and use `\lipsum`, for example (or also `\lipsum[1]` or change numbers).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik classical tex never hyphenates the first word of a paragraph, luatex drops that ---bug--- feature.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ooh, interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

TeX never tries to hyphenate a word that is not preceded by glue. This restriction is lifted in LuaTeX.

On the other hand, if you add `\hspace{0pt}` before the “word”, you still get no hyphenation with `pdflatex`, because TeX stops hyphenating after 63 characters and indeed you get

```
Overfull \hbox (83.33447pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 14--15
 \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-bl
ah-blah-blah-blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah
```

The 16th “blah” group has no hyphen after it, as you see. Since 18 ”blah” groups fit on the line, hyphenating after the 15th would produce a very short line, so this possibility is discarded by TeX, leaving it with the only choice of producing an overfull line.

LuaTeX doesn't have the restriction on 63 characters, but the line turns out to be overfull the same, because no good hyphenation point is found for filling the line.